# Jquery sliding nav performance issue

Tags: jquery, navigation, slidingmenu, sliding

I have implemented a sliding nav and it works incredibly well until you scroll down. Since the $navigation_menu div is fixed i had to write a jquery script to force it to close when the user scrolls down the page and back up the page then tries to use the navigation again the navigation jquery is really slow.

I hope its just something im not aware of in jquery.

Jquery Code

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    var slid = false;
    var right = $("#navigation_menu").css("right");

    $("#navigation").click(function(){
        if(!slid && right == "-300px"){
            $("#navigation_menu").animate({right: '0px'});
            slid = true;
            return;
        }
        else if(slid){
            $("#navigation_menu").animate({right: '-300px'});
            slid = false;
            return;
        }
    });

    $(window).scroll(function(){
        $("#navigation_menu").animate({right: '-300px'});
        slid = false;
        $("$navigation_menu").unbind("scroll");
        return;
    });
});
```

Just to clarify. The navigation closes when the user scrolls down. The navigation opens and closes properly until the user scrolls down. The navigations HTML and CSS is completely correct. Once the user scrolls back down and then scrolls back up to use the navigation it is painfully unresponsive for great amounts of time and takes forever for the navigation to slide into the viewport of the device.

Here is the jsfiddle for the code. Keep in mind this is designed for mobile. I don't know if that makes a difference.

http://jsfiddle.net/371fqnbo/1/

Comment: You can set up the [snippet](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/)? or a http://jsfiddle.net ?

Comment: added jsfiddle example.

Comment: I don't see it in the question..

Comment: There it is. Must not have copied it the first time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Works for me perfectly fine when i only let the animation done when it's needed at scrolling by

```
if(slid){ 
....
}
```

and invoking [.stop()](https://api.jquery.com/stop/) before animations. (Otherwise multiple of those animations will be done since scroll event is triggered multiple times. Those animations end up in the queue of animations. By just invoking animate you put your animation in this queue (and it will be done only AFTER all the other animations are done). By calling stop() you can empty this queue and thus immediately let your animation be done )

Look at http://jsfiddle.net/371fqnbo/2/

However your code contains some redundancies which could be eliminated.

Comment: you're welcome.. i guess everybody who starts doing animations with jQuery and is not aware of animation queue runs once in this kind of issues...

Comment: I am super new to jquery too. I wish i could give you extra reputation points for being friendly. I think some people on here live under bridges or something.